# Using Comparator.nullsFirst not working with reverse()

Tags: java, sorting, reverse, comparator

I am trying to sort Car by three values: first by type, then within the "type" bucket I want to sort those by price (lowest to highest), then if there are any that have the same price, I want to sort by age (newest to oldest).

However, some Cars have a null price. In these cases, I want all the null values to be at the end of the list.

I am trying to use `Comparator.nullsFirst` and `Comparator.nullsLast`, but neither of these are doing anything. I end up getting all the nulls first (regardless of which one I use), then the items sorted on price. I am wondering if it is because I have `.reverse()` which is negating the nullsFirst/Last?

Here is what I am trying:

```
cars.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt((Car car) -> car.getCarMetadata().getCarType().getPriority())
     .thenComparing((Car car -> car.getCarMetadata().getPrice(), Comparator.nullsLast(Double::compareTo)).reversed()
     .thenComparing((Car car) -> car.getAge).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out.. Moving the `reversed()` inside the comparison ended up working, like so:

```
cars.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt((Car car) -> car.getCarMetadata().getCarType().getPriority())
     .thenComparing((Car car -> car.getCarMetadata().getPrice(), Comparator.nullsLast(Double::compareTo)).reversed()
     .thenComparing((Car car) -> car.getAge).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm not sure I totally understand why this fixed it though.

Comment: I don't see the difference between the two code pieces.